# Split lists into lists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list with more listen inside. The list can contain unlimited lists.
I would like to divide these lists in different lists.
Here's an example:

```
data = [[1538406000000, 6569.9680123, 6559.8, 6570, 6551.8, 301.21301548], [1538402400000, 6570, 6569.9, 6572.6, 6500, 1796.34637855], [1538398800000, 6604.7, 6570, 6612.4, 6561, 622.39871899], [1538395200000, 6594.9, 6604.8, 6613.5, 6570, 345.6560351], [1538391600000, 6579.69030138, 6593.9530902, 6603.1, 6555, 1243.109362], [1538388000000, 6617.5, 6579.7, 6622, 6578.6, 344.49315963], [1538384400000, 6628, 6617.5, 6630.2, 6617.4, 231.50416134], [1538380800000, 6602, 6628, 6629.5, 6596.5, 537.99703832], [1538377200000, 6630.4, 6603.9, 6632.12172725, 6600, 135.26208553], [1538373600000, 6627, 6631, 6639.8, 6600, 376.68741732]]

var1 = [data[0][0], data[1][0], data[2][0], ....]
var2 = [data[0][1], data[1][1], data[2][1], ....]
```

How can I automate this?

Many Thanks

Comment: How does your expected output look like? Also, what will be the expected level of nesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that list comprehensions are made for, though I'd argue that keeping your data as the 2D list `data` and pulling out the list comprehension only when you want to consume that data is more idiomatic (anytime you find yourself writing code like: `foo1 = ...; foo2 = ...; foo3 = ...;`, you probably actually want `foo = [..., ..., ...]` which is what `data` already is).

```
var1 = [data[i][0] for i in range(len(data))]
# or, more idiomatically:
# var1 = [lst[0] for lst in data]
var2 = [data[i][1] for i in range(len(data))]
# see above...
```

Though if your intention is just to swap rows for columns (`[ all_zero_indices, all_one_indices, all_two_indices, ...]`) then there's a neat idiom in Python called zip-star.

```
swapped = zip(*data)
```

Note that `zip` returns an iterator, not a list, so you may have to cast as `list` to do listy things like indexing. The first result of `swapped` is then the 0th index of each of `data`'s sublists, and etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = [sublist[0] for sublist in data]
var2 = [sublist[1] for sublist in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your lists can be unlimited I suggest to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1538406000000, 6569.9680123, 6559.8, 6570, 6551.8, 301.21301548], [1538402400000, 6570, 6569.9, 6572.6, 6500, 1796.34637855], [1538398800000, 6604.7, 6570, 6612.4, 6561, 622.39871899], [1538395200000, 6594.9, 6604.8, 6613.5, 6570, 345.6560351], [1538391600000, 6579.69030138, 6593.9530902, 6603.1, 6555, 1243.109362], [1538388000000, 6617.5, 6579.7, 6622, 6578.6, 344.49315963], [1538384400000, 6628, 6617.5, 6630.2, 6617.4, 231.50416134], [1538380800000, 6602, 6628, 6629.5, 6596.5, 537.99703832], [1538377200000, 6630.4, 6603.9, 6632.12172725, 6600, 135.26208553], [1538373600000, 6627, 6631, 6639.8, 6600, 376.68741732]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Printout:

[image]

Now you are very flexible how you want to process your data. E.g.:

```
df.loc[0, :].values
```

gets you the first row as a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(0,len(item[0]):
  print [sublist[x] for sublist in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy

```
initia_data=[[1538406000000, 6569.9680123, 6559.8, 6570, 6551.8, 301.21301548], [1538402400000, 6570, 6569.9, 6572.6, 6500, 1796.34637855], [1538398800000, 6604.7, 6570, 6612.4, 6561, 622.39871899], [1538395200000, 6594.9, 6604.8, 6613.5, 6570, 345.6560351], [1538391600000, 6579.69030138, 6593.9530902, 6603.1, 6555, 1243.109362], [1538388000000, 6617.5, 6579.7, 6622, 6578.6, 344.49315963], [1538384400000, 6628, 6617.5, 6630.2, 6617.4, 231.50416134], [1538380800000, 6602, 6628, 6629.5, 6596.5, 537.99703832], [1538377200000, 6630.4, 6603.9, 6632.12172725, 6600, 135.26208553], [1538373600000, 6627, 6631, 6639.8, 6600, 376.68741732]]
data = np.array(initia_data)
for i in range(len(initia_data[0])):
    print(data[:,i])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't create a variable number of variables

#### Use `dict` or `list` instead

It's tempting to create a new variable for each "column" of data, but don't do this. It obfuscates your code, increasing the complexity of maintaining your code, and ensures you can no longer efficiently handle related variables.

Here's one solution using `dict`:

```
res_dict = dict(enumerate(map(list, zip(*data)), 1))
```

Here's another which simply transposes your list of lists:

```
res_list = list(map(list, zip(*data)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use builtin function `zip` for this as shown below:

```
list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*data))
```

`list1` and `list2` will contain lists as required from the given list `data`

Comment: It will throw too many values to unpack as you will get six different list while trying to store them in just two variables